# Laravel Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I created project in `Laravel 8` and by default the project where created using `PHP 7.3`. In installed and changed to `PHP 7.4`. And it works. But I have some errors:

```
"message": "array_key_exists(): Using array_key_exists() on objects is deprecated. Use isset() or property_exists() instead",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/var/www/api.pboxsystem.pl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php",
    "line": 155,
    "trace": [
```

In my code I changed every `array_key_exists` on `isset` method. But these errors comes from indside of `Laravel` classes. I have to generate project once again and copy all my files?
Is there any way to upgrade `Laravel` to use `PHP 7.4`

Comment: This seems more like an issue to be posted in Laravel framework's GitHub project than on StackOverflow?

Comment: On their webpage I can see that PHP 7.3 min is required, I changed to PHP 7.4 and since now I have that error, but there is no instruction how to upgrade Laravel framework

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade but since it seems to be a fresh installation, you better have to create a fresh project using php 7.4

Comment: yes, it's already ok, I have to change `store` to `storeAs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found bug. I had

```
$path = $file1->store('email_attachments', $filename);
```

in controller and I have to change to:

```
$path = $file1->storeAs('email_attachments', $filename);
```

Now it works